# Получить категории на экран в определённом формате

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив

```
$shop_categories = [
[
    'title' => 'Компьютеры',
    'children' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Ноутбуки',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Моноблоки',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Системные блоки',
            'children' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'Tower',
                ],
                [
                    'title' => 'Mini Tower',
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
[
    'title' => 'Бытовая техника',
    'children' => [
        [
            'title' => 'Пылесосы',
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'Холодильники',
        ]
    ]
]
];
```

Как с помощью одной функции print_cats($shop_categories) легче всего вывести дерево в таком виде:

Компьютеры:

- Ноутбуки
- Моноблоки
- Системные блоки

  - Tower

  - Mini Tower

Бытовая техника:

- Пылесосы
- Холодильники

Comment: `foreach ($shop_categories as $category) { echo $category['title']; if ($category['children']) { print_cats($category['children']);   } }`

Comment: не, такое не пройдёт.. Notice: Undefined index:children в строке if ($category['children'] и расположение категорий просто в столбик одна за одной.

Comment: — Вы, чего, и пальцы за меня загибать будете? — Ага ......... понятно что в столбик (хотя вообще-то в строку)..... не трудно догадаться что вам нужно выводить в `ul` и в `li` или самому стилизовать....или это сложно самому сделать?........ а `if` заменить тогда на `if (isset($category['children']))`

Comment: о, да if (isset($category['children'])) - это ок...теперь всё ясно дальше уже. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function print_cats($shop_categories) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($shop_categories as $category) {
        echo '<li>', $category['title'], '</li>';
        if (isset($category['children'])) {
            print_cats($category['children']);
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

[Проверить](https://www.tehplayground.com/eQa8m6IEUP6b4coe)

Comment: спасибо за это!